# Run Length Encoding (output the length of each repeating sequence in data along with the data value)

Tags: java

I want to output the length of each repeating sequence in some data and the data value. 
So if the data is`7,7,2,9,9,9,3,3,6`
I should get `7 2, 2 1, 9 3, 3 2, 6 1`

I am new to java and unable to debug my code, I have tried running the following code and I am not getting the complete output. I don't understand how to debug this?

```
final int ARRAY_SIZE = 9;
int data[]={7,7,2,9,9,9,3,3,6};
int val=data[0];
int length=1;
for (int index = 1; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++)
if (data[index]==val)
 length++;
 else
{
 System.out.println(val+" with length "+ length);
 val=data[index];
 length=1;
}
```

O/P:

```
7 with length 2
2 with length 1
9 with length 3
3 with length 2
```

Expected O/P:

```
7 with length 2
2 with length 1
9 with length 3
3 with length 2
6 with length 1
```

Comment: Just add a `System.out.println(val+" with length "+ length);` at the end. In the last step your code print `3 with length 2` change the `val` to `6`, set the `length` to `1` and stop because the `index` reach `ARRAY_SIZE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every pass the loop increments the length or prints and then overwrites the previous val and length.

What this misses is the val and length that are in memory after the loop has finished as there is no next element that could print them.

Simply add another println after the end of the loop like this:

```
final int ARRAY_SIZE = 9;
int data[]={7,7,2,9,9,9,3,3,6};
int val=data[0];
int length=1;
for (int index = 1; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++){
    if (data[index]==val)
        length++;
    else {
        System.out.println(val+" with length "+ length);
        val=data[index];
        length=1;
    }
}
System.out.println(val+" with length "+ length);
```